# MVC4: Simplest possible way to get a useful model binding from a string-to-object mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm in an MVC controller. I have a class, and I would like MVC to treat values of this class in exactly the same way it would treat a `Guid` or a `DateTime`; that is:

- When an instance of the class type is written out to a form, it is as a single formatted string and not as separate fields.
- When a value (in string form) is posted back, it is automatically converted back to an instance of the class.

Conceptually, implementing this ought to require only a conversion function for each direction. Say we have one or more objects implementing this interface:

```
namespace SomeExample
{
    public interface SomeStringConversion<T>
    {
        T ConvertFromString(string str);
        string ConvertToString(T obj);
    }
}

// Example: What such a class for Guid might look like
namespace SomeExample
{
    public class SomeGuidStringConversion : SomeStringConversion<Guid>
    {
        public Guid ConvertFromString(string str)
        {
            return Guid.Parse(str);
        }

        public string ConvertToString(Guid g)
        {
            return g.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And say we don't care to validate above and beyond what is accepted or rejected by `ConvertFromString()`.

What is the straightest path (i.e. with as little extraneous detail as possible about unrelated features of model binding) from a collection of `SomeStringConversion<T>` to a controller that uses them?

EDIT: I've been a developer for a good while but I'm fresh meat when it comes to MVC. I need an example with code from which I can work backwards. A high-level description won't be much assistance.

Comment: To clarify, you'd like to read an incoming string representation of an object and bind it to a strong model type and be able to write out a model instance to its string representation in the response?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightfoward way that I can see to implement this would be with a custom model binder.

The binder checks to see if the model type to bind implements the `SomeStringConversion<T>` interface and if it does, attempts to bind the model to the incoming string value. If it doesn't, it simply defers to `DefaultModelBinder` to take the default model binding course of action.

If the string structure is well-formed you may be able to implement a `ValueProvider` to provide the values to a model binder for model binding.